# Ajax not calling success function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cakephp-3.0

I'm using ajax to validate a from without reloadind the page.

**Script Ajax**

```
    function updateResult(tab){
            $.ajax({
                url:"requeteSpecimen.php",
                data:{datas:tab},
                dataType: 'text',
                async:false,
                success: function(data){
                    document.getElementById('resultat').innerHTML = '<p>'+data+'</p>';
                },
                error: function(data){
                    document.getElementById('resultat').innerHTML = '<p>ERROR</p>';
                }
            });
    }

    $("#filtre").submit(function(){
        <?php $tab=$this->request->data; ?>
        updateResult(<?php json_encode($tab);?>);
    });

</script>
```

**requeteSpecimen.php**

```
<?php echo "Success"; ?>
```

My problem is that ajax do not call the sucess function, I always have the "ERROR" text appearing ...

For the moment I don't have yet the code of my requeteSpecimen.php file and I just would like the success function to be called. Don't know if it can help but I'm using cakePHP 3.0.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: well you should tell us what response do you get from the server, check your firebug and tell us about the response tab of you request..

Comment: Look at your browser's developer tools. Look at the JavaScript console. Does it report any errors? Look at the Net tab. Is the request being made? Does it get a response? Do they contain the data you expect? The error function gets passed 3 arguments, use them to find out what sort of error you have if you can't figure it out from the console and net tab.

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing an `e.preventDefault()` to prevent the form from submitting? I also think you have an error. The Network tab or the JS tab should be showing an error. Keep the tab open and see if actually the function is calling and ajax is triggered. Once I had used the `$('.blah').click` instead of `$('#blah').click` and wondering why it was not working...

Comment: in your ajax, how about adding "type: POST"

Comment: Not working with "POST" :/

Comment: 3 people already told you do some debugging, count me in that makes 4... so please, go ahead, debug your stuff, and come back with the results.

Comment: You are using json for delivering and receiving data. change your datatype to JSON. You need to call json object in your success call back function. eg. data.result.id

Answer (score 0):

You do not call actions like that in Cakephp.

First set up an Action in one of your Controllers call the url from your $.ajax function like this.

```
function updateResult(tab){
        $.ajax({
            url:"/controller/request_specimen",
            data:{datas:tab},
            dataType: 'text',
            async:false,
            success: function(data){
                document.getElementById('resultat').innerHTML = '<p>'+data+'</p>';
            },
            error: function(data){
                document.getElementById('resultat').innerHTML = '<p>ERROR</p>';
            }
        });
}
```

You could later on add a route for request_specimen and make it prettier.

In your Controller there should be a method called: `public function request_specimen() {}` Wich will handle the ajax request like so: `if($this->request->is(['ajax']) { /* Handle request */}`

The data sent to the function will be in $this->request->data;

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've tried it and it still doesn't work :/

I think that you're maybe not using cakePHP 3.0 because the syntax you gave me looks like cakePHP 1.3 (not sure of that).

Do you have any other ideas of where the problem could coming from ? 

Ps: I'm not the one who downvoted your answer :/

Comment: It's the same syntax for basic stuff like that

Comment: Check the error_log if you've got access to it, what kind of error message do you recieve, what does the data variable contain in the js ? console.log(data); in the script and check it.