# CakePHP - How to pass url with ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, cakephp

I'm using cakePHP 3.0 and I have a problem while using ajax. Indeed, I would like to execute the action "viewTab" of my controller "SpecimensController" on an array coming from my view "specimen"

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
var tab = new Array();
function updateResult(){
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"<?php echo Router::url(array('controller'=>'specimens','action'=>'index'));?>",
            data:{datas: $("select[name='filtreVariable\\[\\]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get()},
            dataType: 'text',
            async:false,
            success: function(data){
                alert('success');
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
}

$("#filtre").submit(function(){
    updateResult();
});
</script>
```

The action "viewTab" is just doing:

```
echo "success";
```

But I can't find the right url so the function success can be called. I tried many things and I always have the function error of ajax that is called. :/

Comment: Try to debug like `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus,errorThrown){alert('errorThrown')} ;`

Comment: What do you mean about "But I can't find the right url so the function success can be called." ? What URL you cant find?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ajax not calling success function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30002886/ajax-not-calling-success-function)

Comment: -1 You are wasting peoples time, instead of creating duplicate questions, do what you were kindly asked to, debug your code!

Comment: @Sojtin: I'm speaking about the ajax call's url. The one on my code is not working

Comment: But you have controller named "Specimens" and action of this controller named "Index"?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't yet, place this line of code in your AppController where your initialize function is:

```
public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();
    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
}
```

In your controller for the function you're calling via ajax, try something like this:

```
public function index()
{
    $data = ['testing'];
    $this->set(compact('data'));
    $this->set('_serialize', 'data');
}
```

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/request-handling.html